# System.BadImageFormatException occurred in the .NET Framework WPF application of Prism 7.2 that I installed

Tags: wpf, prism

I have created a simple .NET Framework Prism WPF application using Visual Studio 2019. It works without errors in my development environment.

I installed the Visual Studio Intaller Projects extension and added the Setup Project to my solution.

In the Setup project, I added the WPF application, created the installer, ran the installation, and the installation was successful.

When I ran the WPF application, I got a　System.BadImageFormatException.

.NET Framework version is 4.7.2, platform is Any CPU.

This exception does not occur in version 7.1.0.431, but in version 7.2.0.1367 and later (also in version 8.0.0.1909).

Eventviewer error: Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.BadImageFormatException

```
Exception Info: System.BadImageFormatException
   at Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(System.Type, System.String, Unity.Registration.InternalRegistration)
   at Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(System.Type, System.String)
   at Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(System.Reflection.ParameterInfo, System.Object)
   at Unity.Processors.ParametersProcessor`1+<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<CreateParameterResolvers>b__0(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   at Unity.Processors.ConstructorProcessor+<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<GetResolverDelegate>b__0(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2+<>c__DisplayClass8_0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<GetResolver>b__0(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2+<>c__DisplayClass8_0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<GetResolver>b__0(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2+<>c__DisplayClass8_0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<GetResolver>b__0(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   at Unity.UnityContainer+<>c__DisplayClass94_0.<OptimizingFactory>b__0(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   at Unity.Strategies.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   at Unity.UnityContainer+<>c.<.ctor>b__58_1(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)

Exception Info: Unity.ResolutionFailedException
   at Unity.UnityContainer+<>c.<.ctor>b__58_1(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   at Unity.UnityContainer.Unity.IUnityContainer.Resolve(System.Type, System.String, Unity.Resolution.ResolverOverride[])
   at Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve(Unity.IUnityContainer, System.Type, Unity.Resolution.ResolverOverride[])
   at Prism.Unity.Ioc.UnityContainerExtension.Resolve(System.Type)
   at Prism.Ioc.IContainerProviderExtensions.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Prism.Ioc.IContainerProvider)
   at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings(Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterMappings)
   at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.Initialize()
   at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.InitializeInternal()
   at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at PrismApp1.App.Main()
```

Does anyone have an idea?

2020/12/15 Edited

[Configuration Manager capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvApr.png)

[Project Properties capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yGPM.png)

[Setup Project Properties capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlZRu.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! What does your Configuration Manager in Visual Studio tell you about each project?  Usually BadImageFormatException happens when one of your projects is compiled to a specific architecture (e.g. x64), but you forget to use that same architecture up the software stack (such as your Setup project).  For example, Project1 is expected to build as Debug/x64, but the SetupProject is compiled as Debug/AnyCPU.  SetupProject will compile without errors, but when you try to run Project1.exe it fails due to Project1's library dependency that required you to compile it as x64.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added a screen capture.

Comment: Looks like you've checked "Prefer 32-bit" on your setup project properties. Is that intentional? It could be problematic and compile your InstallerSample as 32-bit, when one of its dependencies is 64-bit.

Comment: I tried unchecking Prefer 32-bit, but the error still occurred.
I tried setting the Platform to x86 and x64, but the same thing happened.
I will use version 7.1.0.431 this time. Thank you.

Comment: I got into the same exact situation.